# sql sum rows that have different value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple table that contain duplicate rows, and I want to sum only the rows that have different value,
for example in the table below id (1) is duplicated 4 times but they are the same so I want it to be distinct and id (2) is also duplicated but qty and value column is different so I want to merge it

[image]

so i want this table to be like below when I select it:

[image]

I tried to do this but it sum all the rows but I want to sum only rows that have different value:

```
select ID, SUM(QTY), SUM(VALUE)
FROM TABLE1
GROUB BY ID
```

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` _set quantifier_.

Comment: Add the rows (6, 1, 2) and (6, 1, 3) to the sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly. (To make the problem clearer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option: Use an aggregate function like `MIN` or `MAX` for the id column, group by it and use `SUM(DISTINCT...)` for the other columns:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(ID) AS ID,
  SUM(DISTINCT qty) AS QTY,
  SUM(DISTINCT VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID
```

See this [db<>fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5332b/3) based on your sample data.

You should by the way **rename** the `value` column because this is a SQL key word and issues are likely when using key words as table name or column name.

Renaming the column can be done this way:

```
 ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME COLUMN VALUE TO YourNewColumnName
```

Comment: Jonas Metzler you are genius thanks man it worked

Answer (score 1):

A `SELECT DISTINCT` paired with typical aggregation functions can get you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(QTY) AS QTY, SUM("VALUE") AS "VALUE"
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, QTY, "VALUE" FROM TABLE1
) TABLE1
GROUP BY ID
```

<sup>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5332b/1)</sup>

Comment: thanks @esqew but how to make the same script in sql developer

Comment: SQL Developer is an IDE; does that mean your RDBMS is Oracle? As requested above, please add the tag of the RDBMS you're using. Are you seeing any issues with this code when running it in your Oracle environment?

Comment: @Hbk88 Without more information about why this doesn't work for you, I cannot reproduce any issues with this query in Oracle in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5332b/1).

Comment: yes it says invalid identifier

Comment: @Hbk88 There's nothing anyone here can do for you without you being able to show what the actual issue is, since the error itself is not reproducible with the little information you've given.

Comment: when I run the script I get this error ORA-00904: "VALUE": invalid identifier

Comment: I am using oracle with sql developer

Comment: @Hbk88 `VALUE`, as in most RDBMS', is a reserved keyword. You may have success referring to it using a quoted identifier. Is the column in your table *really* called `VALUE`…?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this,

```
SELECT ID, SUM(QTY) AS QTY, SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM (SELECT ID, QTY, VALUE
       FROM TABLE1 
       GROUP BY ID, QTY, VALUE) a
GROUP BY ID
```